# Como fazer o diretorio do subdominio redirecionar?

Tags: php

Tenho um dominio lostscavenge.com.br e criei um subdominio para ele forum.lostscavenge.com.br que aponta para o fórum scavenge.forumeiros.com tá funcionando certinho tudo beleza, o problema é que se eu acessar lostscavenge.com.br/forum ele abre a pasta vazia do diretorio no navegador, e eu gostaria de fazer com que ele redirecionasse ao fórum forum.lostscavenge.com.br

O que eu posso fazer para isso acontecer? A hospedagem é minha, eu tenho acesso geral ao cpanel e tudo mais...

Answer (score 2):

Crie um arquivo chamado **index.php** e coloque-o na raiz do **/forum**
Neste arquivo, usaremos o comando `header` para redirecionar, conforme abaixo.

```
<?php
   header("Location: http://scavenge.forumeiros.com"); 
?>
```

Caso queira, também podes fazer em ***html/javascript.***

Crie um arquivo **index.html**, com as seguintes linhas:

```
<script language="javascript">
    window.location.href = "http://scavenge.forumeiros.com";
</script>
```

Mas ainda se não quiseres que redirecione, podes criar um arquivo **.htaccess** dentro do diretório em questão, como o exemplo abaixo:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lostscavenge.com.br/forum$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://scavenge.forumeiros.com$1 [P]
```

Nisto, conseguiremos manter a `URL`, com o conteúdo externo.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54637/discussion-on-answer-by-andre-baill-como-fazer-o-diretorio-do-subdominio-redirec)